# How to launch an APP in background in iOS 6.x silently

Tags: objective-c, ios6, jailbreak, launch

We want to launch an APP silently in iPhone without bring this APP to the Foreground. In iOS 5.x we achieve this goal by this code:

```
    [(SBApplication*)app setDisplaySetting:0x4 flag:NO];
    [(SBDisplayStack*)displayStack pushDisplay:app];
    [(SBDisplayStack*)displayStack popDisplay:app];
```

But, in iOS 6.x there is not SBDisplayStack any more. I did some search but not found any answers. Someone says that SBWorkSpace replaces the SBDisplayStack in iOS 6.x. We use SBAppToAppWorkspaceTransaction to implement but always bring the APP to the Foreground which dose not achieve our goal.

Anyone can help me? Thx!

Comment: is your app on appstore? (with iOS5.x version)

Comment: @NikitaP: The app can’t be on the App Store, since the `SBDisplayStack` class is a private one.

Comment: It is a jailbreak App

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `SBSLaunchApplicationWithIdentifier()` function from the `SpringBoardServices` private framework. It takes a `suspended` argument:

```
SBSLaunchApplicationWithIdentifier(CFSTR("com.company.app"), TRUE);
```

You'll also need the `com.apple.springboard.launchapplications` entitlement for this.

Comment: :I've tried the way you said. I need the APP running background so I set suspended = NO, and this setting bring the APP to the Foreground again. any other idea?

Comment: @Cabrite11 Background == suspended. It's not a coincidence I wrote `TRUE` and **not** `FALSE`. Don't be ignorant (alternatively revise highschool maths).

Comment: Maybe in your opinion Background == suspended. But since I know there are APPs enter background without suspending(e.g. which are implement        (UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier)beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:(void(^)(void))handler  NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(4_0);)  Maybe you should revise your primaryschool maths

Comment: @Cabrite11 1. They don't "enter background without suspending", 2. complain after trying the appropriate code only.