# how to open an app by bundle id on iOS

Tags: ios, jailbreak

Just now , I create a project based on Single View Application on Xcode6.3.1, then I create a button on Main.storyboard. The code is like this when the button touched:

```
NSString * bundleId = @"com.apple.iBooks";
void* sbServices = dlopen("/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices", RTLD_LAZY);
int (*SBSLaunchApplicationWithIdentifier)(CFStringRef identifier, Boolean suspended) = dlsym(sbServices, "SBSLaunchApplicationWithIdentifier");
const char *strBundleId = [bundleId cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
int result = SBSLaunchApplicationWithIdentifier((__bridge CFStringRef)bundleId, NO);
dlclose(sbServices);
```

But it did not work.
Then I do like this site tell me , [Launch other application without URL schema in iphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11693796/launch-other-application-without-url-schema-in-iphone)
It did not work,either. Please help me.
My device is iPhone4s, iOS 7.1.2, jailbroken.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to launch an APP in background in iOS 6.x silently](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14999658/how-to-launch-an-app-in-background-in-ios-6-x-silently)

Comment: @creker - thank you for your answer, but maybe the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14999658/how-to-launch-an-app-in-background-in-ios-6-x-silently can not solve my problem

Comment: then you did something wrong. Read about entitlements, without them the code will not work

Comment: I want to know how to configure the entitlements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*** For jail break you can proceed with this ***

There is a mechanism known as `URL scheme`, which can be used to open app from inside your app. but for that you need to do the proper url schemens setUp in your plist file. I strongly feel that you are not looking at this option.

*** There is another way strictly not recommended ( except JAILBREAK PHONES) the API is private ***, but you can do a try & enjoy in development mode.

- `openApplicationWithBundleID` : To open the app using bundle identifier.
- `- (NSArray*)allInstalledApplications;` : This will list you all the installed application on your device.

If you want to see an interesting demo it this, kindly [run this app](https://github.com/lmmenge/WatchSpringboard-Prototype) in your phone & see the ***Apple Watch*** style, spring board, with all apps listed & can be launched on tap.

Hope that gives the better idea of the private api usage.

Comment: With jailbreak there is no such thing as restriction. :)

Comment: @Balram Tiwari - Thank for clarifying. The demo works well. And I solve the problem . In the demo , it gives an idea of the private api usage.

Answer (score 0):

Install the `com.conradkramer.open` **open** package from Cydia and you can run `open com.bundle.id` from shell via SSH or from an app.